# Where to add ES6-Promise Script Tag In ASP.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, es6-promise, powerbi-embedded

I'm using the sample [here](https://github.com/CriticalPathTraining/DailyReporterPro) to embed a Power BI report into a web application.

The application compiles properly, but I'm getting an error involving Promises. I've tracked down the solution [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/issues/54). It seems that I need to add the following somewhere in my application:

```
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/es6-promise@3.2.1"></script>
```

However, I have absolutely no idea where this script tag should go. Any suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The es6-promise library is a polyfill for Promises, mostly used in IE.
If you need it, you just need to put it anywhere in your `<head>` tag, preferably before your `<script src='.../powerbi.js>`.

For more info on es6-promise: https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise